# Excel formula to copy Row Data into Column Data and sort by descending order

Tags: excel

I have data being entered into a ROW on one spreadsheet which I need to have in a COLUMN on another spreadsheet within the same workbook.

Copy, Paste Special and transpose will not do the job as I need the COLUMN to remain actively linked to the ROW, so that as the new row data is entered or amended the column data changes accordingly and then sorted in descending order.

[here is the rank worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCNsg.png)

[worksheet containing the row i need to copy from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bIoa.png)

Comment: Is your data numeric or text ?

Comment: its numeric and after copying I want it  automatically be sorted it into descending order @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 0):

With data in *Sheet1* like:

[image]

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,1,ROWS($1:1))="","",INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,1,ROWS($1:1)))
```

and copy down .  In *Sheet2* cell **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(A:A,ROW()),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

*(this is only an example.  You will need to modify the equations to match your data structure.)*

Comment: Thank you very much @Gary's Student

Comment: I tried modifying your answer but unfortunately I could not manage. I have added the screenshots of my workbook if you can help